# Copy values from a row to another workbook by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, rows

I have this code to copy rows from a sheet to another if the condition is true, but I have a little problem. The cells of Sheet1 have formulas and I want to paste just the values to Sheet2.
How can I do this in this code?

```
Sub CopyRows()     
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
  Dim FName As String
  Dim FPath As String
  Dim NewBook As Workbook

  lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  i = 1

  For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T1:T" & lastRow)
    If cell.Value = "X" Or cell.Value = "Y" Then          
      cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 1)
      i = i + 1
    End If        
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 1)
```

With these two lines instead:

```
cell.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```